# Defining a C++ type in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a .DLL and a .h file. I'm using c#, but the .DLL is written in C++. I have to problem with calling certain function within the .DLL. The problem comes when I need to call functions that have types defined in them . For example include with the .DLL was a .h file and it has a type defined like follows:

```
struct device_info {
  HANDLE dev_handle;  // valid open handle or NULL
  wchar_t* product_string;     // malloc'd string or NULL
  wchar_t* serial_string;     // malloc'd string or NULL
};
typedef struct device_info *PDEV_INFO;
```

I tried to run with it and created a structure like so:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] public struct PDEV_INFO
{
        unsafe void* dev_handle;
        unsafe char* product_string;
        unsafe char* serial_string;

}
```

My program just crashes I try to use any of those types. How would I define these types in C# or how can I reference types from a .h file? Even better would be the types defined somewhere in the .DLL and I'm just unaware. Thanks.

Comment: How are you using these types?

Answer (score 3):

Try IntPtr instead of pointers. IntPtr was designed for Marshalling, c# pointer weren't.
Also, you might want to read up on string marshalling. You really don't need to do that yourself.

Try declaring your type as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
public struct PDEV_INFO
{
        IntPtr dev_handle;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
        String product_string;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] 
        String serial_string;

}
```

Comment: So something like this:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] public struct PDEV_INFO
        {
                unsafe IntPtr* dev_handle;
                unsafe IntPtr* product_string;
                unsafe IntPtr* serial_string;
        }

Comment: No, without the Pointers. Pointers are very un-c# - you should (almost) always avoid them. I've updated my answer to give you an idea.